# Is repeated op_Explicit possible?

Tags: f#

I'm not sure that what I am looking for is possible, but let's try!

I am trying to define an `inline` function `explicit` that will convert a `Box<'t>` into a `'t` to any level of nesting.

The code works as expected for one level (`Box<int> -> int`), however `Box<Box<int>>` is only converted to `Box<int>`, despite the type-annotation on the L.H.S.

```ml
type Box<'t> =
  {
    Item : 't
  }
  with 
    static member inline op_Explicit (x : Box<'t>) : 't = 
      x.Item

let inline explicit<'t, 'u when 't : (static member op_Explicit : 't -> 'u)> (x : 't) : 'u =
  't.op_Explicit x

let x : int = explicit { Item = 123 }
let y : int = explicit { Item = { Item = 123 } }
let z : int = explicit { Item = { Item = { Item = 123 } } }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the short answer is no. The signature of `explicit` clearly unwraps only a single level, and I don't think there's any type-safe way to define the function you want in F#.

It sounds like you actually want the compiler to automatically chain multiple `explicit` calls together? For what it's worth, C# will silently insert a single *im*plicit (not explicit) conversion for you, but even that language won't chain more than one together implicitly.

Comment: This is what I suspected. `explicit2`, `explicit3`, ... isn't so bad though.